# PPTPD VPN Can't connect to the internet

Tags: networking, vpn, bind, pptp, pptpd

I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04 Server on a VMWare ESXI Server with its own public IP, I have setup a pptpd vpn server which works but only with connected devices.
I can't connect to the internet with it however I can connect to the server hosting the vpn or any devices connected to the vpn, I'm trying to set it up as a gateway...

This is my first time experiencing with vpn and I'm no network expert.
I googled my issue, and have tried all of the fixes I could think of.
This is what I tried changing:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in sysctl.conf
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT" in /etc/ufw (firewall)
Disabling the firewall
```

Here are my configs:

/etc/pptpd.conf:

```
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
localip 10.0.0.1
remoteip 10.0.0.10-200
```

/etc/ppp/pptpd-options

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
debug
lock
nobsdcomp
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
```

I have no clue where to start from, I've been tailing the system log greping any data containing 'pptpd' or 'named'

I am however getting a bunch of named messages upon connection, but I'm not quite sure what they are.

```
vpn named[15200]: automatic empty zone: 10.IN-ADDR.ARPA
vpn named[15200]: automatic empty zone: 17.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
vpn named[15200]: automatic empty zone: 18.172.IN-ADDR.ARPA
etc...
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You should not be using PPTP. It's horribly insecure and there are other options that are not only more secure, but also easier to manage.

Comment: @EEAA Do you have any suggestions in mind? is L2TP a better choice?